# Why don't I see all the planes in the ChromaticityPlot3D?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

Using the default setting, I can have my desired `ChromaticityPlot3D` as

```
ChromaticityPlot3D["LAB", "LAB"];
```

However, the problem with this plot is that it has (probably) the `PlotRange` as `{{0.,1.},{-1.3,1.3},{-1.3,1.3}}` and I don't want these additional ranges beyond `{-1.,1.}`.

Therefore, when I set the `PlotRange` as `{{0.,1.},{-1.,1.},{-1.,1.}}` I can see only the top and the bottom planes (using the default view setting).

Is it possible to have the `PlotRange` as `{{0.,1.},{-1.,1.},{-1.,1.}}` and still see the `ChromaticityPlot3D` as it is seen with the default settings?

**Edit 1** Or may be the ranges for the CIE LAB is considered as `{0,1},{-1.28,1.27},{-1.28,1.27}`

Answer (score 2):

```
cp = ChromaticityPlot3D["LAB", "LAB"]
```

[image]

```
PlotRange[cp]
```

> {{2.22045*10^-16, 1.}, {-1.28, 1.28}, {-1.28, 1.28}}

```
cp2 = cp /.  GraphicsComplex[x_, p__] :>  GraphicsComplex[ 
  Transpose[{#, Clip[#2, {-1, 1}], Clip[#3, {-1, 1}]} & @@ Transpose[x]], p]
```

[image]

```
PlotRange[cp2]
```

> {{2.22045*10^-16, 1.}, {-1., 1.}, {-1., 1.}}

Comment: This rescales the whole picture. The slices would look different on different planes I think.

Answer (score 2):

We can plot our own version:

```
RegionPlot3D[
  -1 <= a <= 1 && -1 <= b <= 1 && 0 <= L <= 1,
  {a, -1, 1}, {b, -1, 1}, {L, 0, 1}, 
  Axes -> True,
  AxesLabel -> SuperStar /@ {"a", "b", "L"},
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{a, b, L}, LABColor[L, a, b]], 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
  Lighting -> "Neutral", 
  Mesh -> None
]
```

[image]